# how to control jvm heap usage rate to stay below 80% as much as possible?

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory, garbage-collection, g1gc

Our springboot app is used for get large data and compress it. so it always needs large memory.But customer's Prometheus always monitor it and send alarm to us heap memory usage rate exceeds 80%.Though we know it won't oom and restart ... but we are boring to explain ,so we try to let GC occurs in advance ,avoiding threshold 80% . of course, as much as possile, not absolutely.

PS:
jdk1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75

Comment: *"But customer's Prometheus always monitor it and send alarm to us heap memory usage rate exceeds 80%."* - I think that the best thing would be to tell your customer to either adjust their alarm levels or reduce the max heapsize.

Comment: You don't need large amounts of memory to compress large objects. It can always be done in a streaming manner. Examine your assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you ensure that your application doesn't create objects in the heap the usage of the heap memory should not increase. That's usually impractical and not really feasible in real life.

You could profile and try to minimize the usage of memory and the time it is kept in memory. However there are no guarantees how much success you will have.

Having said that, this is a common situation caused by wrong expectations from user of how the JVM memory works and how to monitor it. Educating your customer could be useful.

Another option could be monitor the memory patterns of the application in real life conditions and adjust the monitoring alarm to those conditions.

Comment: users will send many requests to our app ,then app will continueously extract data from DB. So it will frequently create objects in heap. We know that exceeding 80% was common,but boring to explain it to those who know nothing about java, so we are trying to reduce the alarm counts , eg . by forcing GC when reaching 75% .

Comment: That it is boring to explain something is not a good technical reason. Forcing GC at a fixed percentage of the heap may impact performance. Have you performed benchmarking with different configurations to understand the impacts of the changes?